# Compiler error when trying to calculate Variance of a set of data

Tags: java, arrays, double

im trying to calculate the variance of a the set of data inputted by a user. However, when i run my program, im getting the error: method variance in class Test cannot be applied to given types.
This is my code so far:

```
public static double variance(ArrayList<Double> numbers, double mean) {

    double variance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <numbers.size(); i++) {
        variance = variance + Math.pow((numbers.get(i) - mean(numbers)), 2);
    }
    return variance/numbers.size();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter data set: ");
    ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
        nums.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
    }
    double numbs = mean(nums);
    System.out.println("Mean = " + numbs);
    double numbs2 = variance(nums);
    System.out.println("Variance = " + numbs2);
  }
}
```

I have a method above the Variance method which calculates the mean of the ArrayList, would that be useful in anyways, despite me initialising a double mean in the variance method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Adjust your `variance` method to accept one argument, like so

   ```
      public static double variance(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
           double variance = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i <numbers.size(); i++) {
               variance = variance + Math.pow((numbers.get(i) - mean(numbers)), 2);
           }
           return variance/numbers.size();
       }
   ```
2. Define the method `mean` similar to this, and the rest should be fine.

   ```
   public static double mean(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
      double sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        sum += numbers.get(i);
      }
     return sum / numbers.size();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

your `variance` method need **2** parameter but when you invoke it you give just **one** param

Comment: So should I get rid of the "double mean" parameter? Or is there a way to use it so that I don't have to rid it off and implement it in my code?

Comment: where is `mean` method defined?

Comment: This is the mean method: 

public static double mean(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
  
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
   sum = sum + numbers.get(i);
  }
  return sum/numbers.size();
 }

Comment: i'm not sure but i think u can remove `double mean`  param from parameters list

Comment: @ShahrokhAryana, see my answer